# Does Android support Apache POI API

Tags: android, api, apache-poi

I am working on PPT VIEWER, The work i want to perform is to convert all slides to images in android. I want to know does android really support Apache POI API.If not,then what other options are present.I would be happy if you provide me a sample code[any example code] of android with Apache POI API support.

Comment: This discussion will help you:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8493507/trying-to-port-apache-poi-to-android

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can certainly port Apache POI API in Android. The example code that i made is to count the number of slides in a power point presentation with the help of Apache POI.
[image]

Comment: what this screen shot make a sense

Comment: yes,it takes the input and count the number of slides present in the slide