# Bundle a file inside app in Android

Tags: android, file, bundle, apk

What I want to do is to have the user press a button of some sort and inside the method of that button I want the system to open up a file (in this case a .docx file) inside a file viewer this would have to be done via an intent but how should that be coded and where do I put my .docx file?

Comment: Android doesn't support .docx file directly.

Comment: Try this
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4249897/how-to-send-objects-through-bundle

Answer (score 0):

Android doesn't have inbuilt functionality for viewing **.docx** file.

for that,

Your android device should installed **.docx** viewer (Third party like, Documents To Go, Smart Office, Quickoffice) application then you can open that file using `Intent`.

something like,

```
Intent intent = new Intent();
intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
String type = "application/msword";
intent.setDataAndType(Uri.fromFile(docx file), type);
startActivity(intent);
```

But if any **.docx** viewer is not installed then you can direct user to first install that application using Android Market and then after download that app you can open your **.docx** file in it.

Or you can integrate **.docx** viewer functionality in application using third party library. I think **Apache's docx4j** is in java.

Comment: I assume tried this out but it's giving me an error. I placed my .docx file in /res/raw and named it test.docx. This is my code:                        Intent intent = new Intent();        intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
    String type = "application/msword";
    intent.setDataAndType(Uri.fromFile(R.raw.test), type);
    startActivity(intent);

Comment: Method'android.net.Uri.fromFile(java.io.File)'in 'android.net.Uri' can not be applied to '(int)'

Comment: Copy your .docx file from raw folder to sdcard or internal storage then pass uri of that copied file from that place.. It works..

Comment: How would I copy the file to the internal storage? And then should I replace the "R.raw.test" with something like "/sdcard/files"?

Comment: This may help you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10548530/validating-and-reading-a-word-file-in-android