# Android:Read Text from word file with same formatting

Tags: android

I want to build an android app which has word file as an input. I should be able to read from the word file and display the text. Text should retain all the formatting of the word file. For example is some text is colored red in word file , app should also display it as red colored text.

Answer (score 0):

2 different libraries comes to my mind on handling microsoft office stuff are Apache POI and docx4j. Have you tried them on your purpose, because they have good API support for retrieving data from documents.

I used Apache POI for excel sheet and I know that it has a good api support for word doc too, but I heard that docx4j is better in handling word documents.

Some links you might check : for Apache POI [Validating and reading a Word file in Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10548530/validating-and-reading-a-word-file-in-android)

for more info on word documents : [What's a good Java API for creating Word documents?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/203174/whats-a-good-java-api-for-creating-word-documents)

Also please check following link if you are going with Apache POI; you might fail on adding library to your project.. [Trying to port Apache POI to Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8493507/trying-to-port-apache-poi-to-android)

Comment: docx4j is very good in terms of its results but takes a while to get into because you have to understand the structure of a `.docx` file. More importantly, it works only with `.docx` and not with `.doc`, so it's not an option if you want to handle old Word documents.